# _meta field in elasticsearch usage?

Tags: elasticsearch, meta

In my scenario , i have two applications(i.e.A,B) both will push documents to ES .Normally in the slowlogs we can able to get the

`[2016-03-23 06:43:47,231][DEBUG][index.search.slowlog.fetch] took[5.8ms], took_millis[5], types[talk], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"match":{"tags":"Java"}}}], extra_source[]`

Suppose if i had enabled the _meta field in ES , is it possible to reflect the field in slowlogs like this?

`[2016-03-23 06:43:47,231][DEBUG]`[Application]`[index.search.slowlog.fetch] took[5.8ms], took_millis[5], types[talk], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"match":{"tags":"Java"}}}], extra_source[]`

I want to know whether the document pushed from application A or B? Is it possible in ES?

I went to the documentation of [_meta field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html) but didnt get clear info on that , if possible please put some light on that?

Doc also says that this field is `not used by Elasticsearch`. What does this stmt mean , means I can't able to do perform any operations on this field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use it for that (unless I'm misunderstanding the question).

The `_meta` field in the template will be added to the index, not the documents. Also you'd need to have the attribute in the query, so that the slowlog could potentially use it (though there is no such concept as far as I know).

To get a better understanding of `_meta` you might want to play through the following steps in Console (or translate them to cURL.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "_meta": { 
        "class": "MyApp::User",
        "version": {
          "min": "1.0",
          "max": "1.3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET my_index/_mapping

PUT my_index/user/1
{
  "foo": "bar"
}

GET my_index/_mapping

GET my_index/user/1

DELETE /my_index
```

Comment: Thanks @xeraa .Based on your answer i can able to say `_meta` is applied to the index type . But in the _meta field `"class": "MyApp::User"` what this line actually mean?

Comment: Inside `_meta` you can put any JSON document you want. The attributes `class`,... are just attributes picked for that example.

Comment: IN documentation they had specified `These are not used at all by Elasticsearch, but can be used to store application-specific metadata`. Application Specific Metadata means ` I can add anything in this field right? and also i cant use any aggregations on that since it is not used byES ?

Comment: Yes, you can add any JSON document there. No, you cannot use this for aggregations. This is not part of your documents; it's only part of the metadata of your index. You'll only get it back with `GET my_index/_mapping`

Comment: Thanks @xeraa it really helped. SO, there is no possibility of getting this in slowlogs right?